# How can I reduce the code duplication on Tkinter to create grids and labels?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a user interface with Tkinter and there are a lot of labels and the command to create them it's very repetitive. I know in my guts there's a better more elegant way to do this but I don't know what it is :D

Could you please advise me how you would reduce my 100+lines?

```
import tkinter as tk

'create window'

BLK_Window = tk.Tk()
BLK_Window.title('Blackrock Primary Custom Baskets')
BLK_Window.geometry('1280x720')
BLK_Window.resizable(width=0, height=0)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(4,minsize=50)

'set up min size for each column'

BLK_Window.columnconfigure(5,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(6,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(7,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(8,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(9,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(10,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(11,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(12,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(13,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(14,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(15,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(16,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(17,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(18,minsize=50)
BLK_Window.columnconfigure(19,minsize=50)

'create every label'

A_L1 = tk.Label(text="1)")
A_L1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

A_L2 = tk.Label(text="Event Description")
A_L2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

A_E1 = tk.Entry(BLK_Window)
A_E1.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

A_L3 = tk.Label(text="EV Score")
A_L3.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

A_E2 = tk.Entry(BLK_Window)
A_E2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

A_L5 = tk.Label(text="Ticker",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L5.grid(row = 0, column = 5,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L6 = tk.Label(text="Shs",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L6.grid(row = 0, column = 6,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L7 = tk.Label(text="MV",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L7.grid(row = 0, column = 7,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L8 = tk.Label(text="Units",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L8.grid(row = 0, column = 8,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L9 = tk.Label(text="Cr/Re",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L9.grid(row = 0, column = 9,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L10 = tk.Label(text="AP/MM",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L10.grid(row = 0, column = 10,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L11 = tk.Label(text="Type",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L11.grid(row = 0, column = 11,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L12 = tk.Label(text="Feedback",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L12.grid(row = 0, column = 12,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L13 = tk.Label(text="OP Cutoff",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L13.grid(row = 0, column = 13,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L14 = tk.Label(text="LG Cutoff",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L14.grid(row = 0, column = 14,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L15 = tk.Label(text="BBG Ticker",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L15.grid(row = 0, column = 15,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L16= tk.Label(text="Market Cap",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L16.grid(row = 0, column = 16,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L17 = tk.Label(text="Fund AUM",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L17.grid(row = 0, column = 17,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L18 = tk.Label(text="Min",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L18.grid(row = 0, column = 18,sticky="E"+"W")

A_L19 = tk.Label(text="Max",borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
A_L19.grid(row = 0, column = 19,sticky="E"+"W")

A_O5 = tk.Label(master=BLK_Window)
A_O5.grid(row = 1, column = 5)

A_O6 = tk.Label(master=BLK_Window)
A_O6.grid(row = 1, column = 6)

A_O7 = tk.Label(master=BLK_Window)
A_O7.grid(row = 1, column = 7)

'function to sqr and apply to 3 cells'

def sqr():
    x1 = A_E2.get()
    x2 = (float(x1))**2
    A_O5["text"] = x2
    A_O6["text"] = x2
    A_O7["text"] = x2
    
A_B2 = tk.Button(
    master=BLK_Window,
    text="Text",
    command=sqr
)
A_B2.grid(row = 1, column = 3,sticky="E"+"W")

A_B1 = tk.Button(text ="Check")
A_B1.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

BLK_Window.mainloop()
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: First of all, use: `BLK_Window.columnconfigure(tuple(range(5, 20)),minsize=50)` instead of all of those statements. Second of all, use for loops

Comment: you can also use list or nested lists to keep track of your buttons. You then might just need to modify some text of the buttons using the ```.config``` function. If its different texts you might have to make a second list that has the same sizes as the first one and loop through both of them and assign the text of the second list to the button object at the matching index of the first list.

Comment: Instead of creating individual reference variables, use those names as keys to a dictionary that holds all your labels.  Each dictionary entry can contain a tuple with the row, column, stickiness, value.  Then you can write a loop that configures each entry based on the dictionary values.

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating variables with a number as part of a name, that's usually a sign that you can store the objects in a list or dictionary. In this case, however, it doesn't look like you need to store the label variables at all.

You can create them in a loop, and configure the columns in the same loop. If you need to keep references to the labels, I recommend you store them in a dictionary.

```
label_widgets = {}
labels = ("Ticker", "Shs", "MV", "Units", "Cr/Re", "AP/MM", "Type",
          "Feedback", "OP Cutoff", "LG Cutoff", "BBG Ticker",
          "Market Cap", "Fund AUM", "Min", "Max")

for c, text in enumerate(labels):
    column = c+5
    label = tk.Label(BLK_Window, text=text, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
    label_widgets[text] = label
    label.grid(row=0, column=column, sticky="ew")
    BLK_Window.grid_columnconfigure(column, minsize=50)
```

With that, you can later reference the label widget by its text:

```
label_widgets["OP Cutoff"].configure(...)
```